# Python: ModuleNotFoundError: No Module name 'mysql'

Tags: python, mysql

Trying to connect python to MySQL.  Seem to be a lot on this issue but nothing seems to be working for me.  If I am at the Python prompts I can enter my script line by line and have success.

```
>>> import mysql.connector as m
>>> m.__version__
'8.0.22'
```

But when I run the above two lines in my python script (named dbsql.py) I get the error:

```
File "C:\Users\gbran\PythonCode\dbsql.py", line 1, in <module>
  import mysql.connector as m

ModuleNotFoundError: No mdoule named 'mysql'
```

I am new to Python, but wondering if this is a PATH issue within Widnows.  Is there a way in the Python Prompt to see where the file mysql.connector is importing from to ensure the path is available for the script.  Or is there something else I am missing here?

Thanks for any direction and help!

Answer (score 0):

Use pip to search the available module

```
$ pip search mysql-connector | grep --color mysql-connector-python
   

mysql-connector-python-rf (2.2.2)        - MySQL driver written in Python
mysql-connector-python (2.0.4)           - MySQL driver written in Python
```

Install the mysql-connector-python-rf

```
$ pip install mysql-connector-python-rf
```

Verify

```
$ python
Python 2.7.11 (default, Apr 26 2016, 13:18:56)
[GCC 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-54)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import mysql.connector
>>>
```

For python3 and later use the next command: `$ pip3 install mysql-connector-python-rf`

Answer (score 0):

You can use sys module to find out the path from where mysql is getting imported.

In the example, I can see that my OS module is getting imported from /usr/lib/python3.8/os.py

```
>>> import sys
>>> import os
>>> sys.modules['os']
<module 'os' from '/usr/lib/python3.8/os.py'>
>>>
```

Then add that path to your PYTHONPATH so that python can import modules from there.

See another example below:

```
user@user-Inspiron:~$ python3
Python 3.8.5 (default, Jul 28 2020, 12:59:40) 
[GCC 9.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sample_module
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sample_module'
>>> 
user@user-Inspiron:~$ echo $PYTHONPATH

user@user-Inspiron:~$ export PYTHONPATH=/tmp/
user@user-Inspiron:~$ echo $PYTHONPATH
/tmp/

user@user-Inspiron:~$ python3
Python 3.8.5 (default, Jul 28 2020, 12:59:40) 
[GCC 9.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sample_module
>>> sample_module.does_it_work
'It Works!'
>>>
```